# Stuck at Who are you?

Tags: system-installation

I had Windows and Ubuntu installed. I removed them both. Then tried to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 again.
But it is now stuck at "Who are you?" page. 
N.B: Given my username in all lowercase. I am trying to install it offline in "minimal installation". 
Any solution?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Did you hashckeck the downloaded ISO? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1469728/edit) and post a photo?